# changing multiple permissions with one single command

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions

I have a directory say `foo` with permission `rw-r----x`. I want to change the permission to `r-xr--r-x`. I can do it like `chmod u-w foo, chmod u+x foo, chmod o+r foo`. I was wondering if there is a way to combine these three commands into one without using octal numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just list with commas.

```
$ ls -l file
-rw-r----x 1 tomasz tomasz 0 Aug 12 22:24 file
$ chmod u-w,u+x,o+r file
$ ls -l file
-r-xr--r-x 1 tomasz tomasz 0 Aug 12 22:24 file
```

You can also use the = syntax.

```
$ chmod u=rw,g=x,o=rwx file 
$ ls -l file 
-rw---xrwx 1 tomasz tomasz 0 Aug 12 22:24 file
```

Comment: @Bib That's what I use, even 0545. But the question excluded octals.